# Any way to run JUnit 5 integration tests in parallel under failsafe?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5, maven-failsafe-plugin

Trying revisit running Junit 5 / 4 integration tests under Junit 5 platform (5.3.2) in maven. from
[How to run a mix of JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests in parallel using maven-failsafe-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934751/how-to-run-a-mix-of-junit-4-and-junit-5-tests-in-parallel-using-maven-failsafe-p)

Running unit tests under surefire plugin 2.22.1 works fin in parallel and mixed tests of JUnit 5 and JUnit 4 and see worker threads in the verbose.

Tried doing the same in failsafe 2.22.1, but takes a log time and no parallel execution is seemed. Also only [main] is printed in the verbose and no worker threads.

Does failsafe supports threads / concurrent execution in Junit 5 platform ? if so, how ?

Also I use the config params :

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=6
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this configuration inside failsafe:

```
<configuration>
  <configurationParameters>
    junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
    junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
    junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default =concurrent            
  </configurationParameters>
<configuration>
```

Comment: @KajHejer yes. it worked fine with my project. hope to be helpful to you